# Calculate age for specific year in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Please i need help about oracle sql! I try to get age from birth date but it's not working from the year 1940 ! My query is

```
select months_between(sysdate, '11/01/40') from dual
```

and the answer i get is  **-19!**

*The calculation works up to year 1950*

Answer (score 0):

If you use a proper ANSI date literal, with the full year component, it works:

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, date '1940-01-11') FROM dual;
```

Assuming your dates are stored as text `DD/MM/YY`, you may use `TO_DATE` instead:

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, TO_DATE(date_col, 'DD/MM/YY)
FROM yourTable;
```

If the above does not work, it could be because `40` is being interpreted as 2040, not 1940.  Please use the full 4 digit date whenever possible, and also avoid storing your dates as text.

Comment: Okey i will try it now!

Comment: it works ! but the problem is that the date format of sysdate and the birth date in my database is **DD/MM/YY** !! 
so how should i proceed ??

Comment: my date_col is store as date  in this format **DD/MM/YY**

Comment: date (including the one you get form sysdate) doesn't have any format, it is a date. The way it is displayed however, is a different thing - it could be varchar2 for example. DB implicitly converts the date to character representation using to_char function. You can do it explicitly yourself and provide required format: `to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')`. What IDE/Editor do you use to run the queries?

Comment: I have already tried that but it still shows me the same date format !!

Comment: sorry, my bad, instead of to_date please use `to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

Comment: thank you all! I have changed the format of the sysdate ```alter session set nls_date_format = 'rrrr-mm-dd';```and from birth date! it is working now

Comment: NOOOO!  You did _not_ change the format of SYSDATE.  You changed the format of the text string used tod _display_ SYSDATE and any other  DATE.  Your entire problem is that you re-created the Y2k  issue. And even now you are somewhat recreating ti by using the RRRR format mask.  That was just meant to be a temporary fix - 20 years ago!.  Use 'YYYY'.  You still don't understand the difference between a DATE and a STRING representation of a DATE. For more in depth, read this article I wrote, at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/dealing-with-dates/